# ExecuteScript returns null in Appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I am using *Appium*, *WebDrive* and [Selenium for C#](http://seleniumhq.org) to test some app on my Android device. The device on which I am testing is not important, just reporting for completeness.

I do the following at a certain point:

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(...);
var isNull = driver.ExecuteScript("window == null;");
```

My test works and it is executed (both on device and simulator), however `isNull` is always `null`.

How to return from `ExecuteScript`?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell WebDriver to "return" it - in the same way that if you didn't specify a "return" value from a method, it wouldn't return anything.

```
var isNull = driver.ExecuteScript("return window == null;");
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, but it makes sense because  read 1h ago that it executes the code in the form of an anonymous function... Thank you very much, I'll let you know in 12h :)